# How to freeze the outlook window on VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a problem with `MessageBox` dialog, normally, the MessageBox will freeze and block the windows, and show on the top of the current windows till user click the messagebox button, but I got the the messagebox cannot block and freeze the current windows on **`VSTO`** ribbon button

```
private async void BtnTest_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("before");

    var task = await DoSomethingAsync();

    MessageBox.Show("after");
}

private async Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return true;
}
```

The first MessageBox can freeze the windows, but the second cannot not be, after investigate I found it caused by the await, when I await till `DoSomethingAsync` finished, the second MessageBox will normally freeze and block the current windows

```
private void BtnTest_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("before");

    var task = DoSomethingAsync();
    task.Wait();
    var result = task.Result;

    MessageBox.Show("after");
}
```

but I don't want block the `Office Outlook Robbin` UI, so I want to execute the `DoSomethingAsync` asynchronous, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: So does it mean? the second message box is shown, but you can still interact with the main Outlook window even the message box is shown?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes, you are right

Comment: That means the message box is not correctly parented - cast Application.ActiveWinow to IOleWindow and call IOleWindows::GetWindow to get the window HWND. You can then use it to show the message box.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a secondary thread using the `Thread.Start` method instead:

```
using System.Threading;

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
thread.Start();
```

where the `WorkThreadFunction` method should look like the following one:

```
public void WorkThreadFunction()
{
  try
  {
     // do any background work
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     // log errors
  }
}
```

Also I'd recommend specifying the parent window handle to the `Show` method. You can cast an instance of the Inspector or Explorer class to the [IOleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface which provides the [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687282(v=vs.85).aspx) function which retrieves a handle to one of the windows participating in in-place activation.

Then you can create an instance of the `IWin32Window` interface which can be passed to the Show method:

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
   public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
   {
       _hwnd = handle;
   }

   public IntPtr Handle
   {
       get { return _hwnd; }
   }

   private IntPtr _hwnd;
 }
```

Comment: IWin32Window window = Control.FromHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle); MessageBox.Show(window, "after"); but it still not work

Comment: I don't think this is caused by missing the owner IWin32Window, because the first MessageBox can lock the current Outlook Email Item window successfully

Comment: Have you tried using the `Thread.Start` method instead of tasks?

Comment: I tried it, if the WorkThreadFunction() cost times, it will block the UI, so I need async, show the messageBox normally at the same time, do you have a better way?